# Array Replication Function in JavaScript using self-executing inner function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write an array replication function in JavaScript that will take an array and a replication factor as input parameters, and return that replicated array.

Like such:

```
expect(replicate([2,3,4],2).toEqual([2,3,4,2,3,4]));
```

And I'm trying to accomplish this with a recursively-called, self-executing inner function that should return the desired value to the outer function when finished.

The inner function seems to work correctly:

```
var replicate = function (inputArray, n) {
    var outputArray = [];
    return (function replicateInner(n) {
        if (n > 0) {
            outputArray.push(inputArray.slice(0));
            replicateInner(--n)
        } else {
            alert('inner function returns: ' + outputArray);
            //inner function returns: [2,3,4,2,3,4]
            return outputArray;
        }
    })(n);

 };
```

But when I call the outer function, it returns undefined

```
alert(replicate([2,3,4],2)); // returns undefined, not [2,3,4,2,3,4]
```

Any idea what I might be missing here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are not returning the result from `replicateInner(--n)`, like this

```
return replicateInner(--n);
```

Also, when you push the `inputArray.slice(0)` to `outputArray`, the result will be like this

```
[ [ 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 3, 4 ] ]
```

What you need to do is to concatenate the arrays like this

```
outputArray = outputArray.concat(inputArray.slice(0));
```

with this change, the output becomes

```
[ 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks! Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/databass/hX8Qk/

Comment: @DavidByman Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Comment: But I do get the same results whether using push or concat.

Comment: @DavidByman Are you sure? When you use `.push`, you would be getting an array of array.

Comment: @DavidByman Correct, you are getting two arrays, right? But you don't want that.

Comment: It becomes more clear if you `alert(JSON.stringify(replicate([2, 3, 4], 2)));`

Answer (score 1):

Awesome question.  Here is a simplified answer that has both an IIFE and the recursion.  We don't need to pass anything around or pass anything to the IIFE since it is all in closure scope.

```
var replicate = function (inputArray, n) {
    var outputArray = [];
    (function replicateInner() {
        if (n > 0) {
            outputArray = outputArray.concat(inputArray.slice(0));
            --n;
            replicateInner()
        }
    })();
    return outputArray;
};
```

Comment: this is much cleaner. Thanks!